# How to get App Memory Usage in Windows Store 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, memory, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1-universal

In my universal Windows Phone 8.1 app I use `Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsage and Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit` to get used/free memory for debug purposes. But in Windows 8.1 version of it Windows.System.MemoryManager api is not found. When I launch app I see in VS2015 memory usage, but I'd prefer to see it in app when launched standalone.

Is there a way to get it in Win 8.1 (not Win 10)?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8.0/8.1 app, there does not exist such a API. For debug purposes, the only we can do currently is to check the [health report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/health-report) in Windows Dev Center. Please refer to the answer in this [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3e25d1ea-7af2-472d-ba24-450a6741622a/w81how-to-detect-memory-usage-in-windows-store-windows-881-app?forum=wpdevelop) by MSFT @Franklin Chen to know more details.

I can understand this could affect your achievement of your Windows 8.1 Store app development. You may submit a feature request if you really need it at **[uservoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform)** site so that MSFT might add it to their to-do-list.

You can click the combobox to check the request status like below:
[image]

Comment: go to site and check health report to see actual memory usage for this particular second, seriously? Ok, for Win Store it is not a big problem (like for wp)